# How to use selector to find a set of list with specific attribute type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, haml, attr

I am using HAML to implement a user display in a page

```
%li
  %label.user
    %input{value: "<%= user.nickname %>", type: "<%= user.type %>", user_avatar: "<%= user.avatar_url %>"}
      %img{src: "<%= user.avatar_url %>"}
      .name <%= user.nickname %>
```

I have 2 user types, "friends" or "followings". My intention is to find and hide all the 'li's with the type = 'following'. How can I do this?

I tried with the following code to no avail.

```
@$('ul.inputs-list li').find('input').attr('type'=='following').hide()
```

Can anyone advise me on how to modify my code so that I can hide all 'li's with type='following'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
@$('ul.inputs-list li').find('input[type="following"]').hide()
```

Comment: Although I was able to successfully select all the 'li's with typ=following, I wasn't able to successfully hide them with the .hide(). Any ideas why? Do I need to iterate through the array and hide them one by one?

Comment: You shouldn’t have to iterate. Something else must be happening.

Comment: @Zhen I'm not sure about that, there must be something else conflicting with it. I'd have to see the rest of your JS/CSS to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
@$('ul.inputs-list li').find('input[type=following]').hide();
```

or

```
@$('ul.inputs-list li input[type=following]').hide();
```